# Merge and overwrite repeating xml nodes using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

I have got a source XML

```
<Records>
  <Data>
    <RecordType>New</RecordType>
    <Number>4734122946</Number>
    <DateOfBirth>20160506</DateOfBirth>
    <Title>Mr</Title>
    <ChangeTimeStamp>20160101010001</ChangeTimeStamp>
    <SerialChangeNumber>01</SerialChangeNumber>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <RecordType>New</RecordType>
    <Number>4734122946</Number>
    <LastName>Potter</LastName>
    <DateOfBirth>20160506</DateOfBirth>
    <ChangeTimeStamp>20160101010002</ChangeTimeStamp>
    <SerialChangeNumber>01</SerialChangeNumber>
  </Data>
</Records>
```

I want to use XSLT 1.0 to produce the below output

```
<Contact>
  <Number>4734122946</Number>
  <Title>Mr</Title>
  <LastName>Potter</LastName>
  <BirthDate>20160506</BirthDate>
  <ChangeTimeStamp>20160101010002</ChangeTimeStamp>
</Contact>
```

The XSLT has to group and merge the child nodes of Data records into one based on the Number field. Also if there are same elements present, then it should use the `ChangeTimeStamp` element to figure out the latest change and use that element.

I tried the below XSLT. But I am nowhere close to the output.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="groups" match="Data" use="Number"/>
  <xsl:key name="sortGroup" match="Data" use ="ChangeTimeStamp"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Records">
    <xsl:for-each select="Data[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups',Number))]">
      <Contact>
        <Number>
          <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
        </Number>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('groups',Number)">
          <xsl:for-each select="key('sortGroup',ChangeTimeStamp)">
            <xsl:sort select="sortGroup" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:if test="Title">
              <Title>
                <xsl:value-of select ="Title"/>
              </Title>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="LastName">
              <LastName>
                <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
              </LastName>
            </xsl:if>
            <BirthDate>
              <xsl:value-of select="DateOfBirth"/>
            </BirthDate>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Contact>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: The output you show will not be valid XML if there are multiple `Contact` nodes in the result. -- Note also that your attempt at Muenchian grouping is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The XSLT has to group and merge the child nodes of Data records into
>   one based on the Number field. Also if there are same elements
>   present, then it should use the ChangeTimeStamp element to figure out
>   the latest change and use that element.

For that, I believe you would want to do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="group" match="Data" use="Number"/>
<xsl:key name="item" match="Data/*" use="concat(../Number, '|', name())"/>

<xsl:template match="/Records">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="Data[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', Number)[1])]">
            <Contact>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('group', Number)/*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item', concat(../Number, '|', name()))[1])]">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('item', concat(../Number, '|', name()))">
                        <xsl:sort select="../ChangeTimeStamp" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Contact>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You will have to make some adjustments if you want to include only some data items and/or if you want them to appear in particular order. If you have a list of all possible data item names (e.g. Title, LastName, DateOfBirth, etc.) then this could be simpler.

Comment: @michel.hor257k Fantastic. Works very well. Just one question regarding performance. The code has to process around 50K Data nodes. Will it cause a performance issue?

Comment: I don't know. Why don't you try it and see for yourself? Make sure to test this with the same processor that will be used in production. In any case, I don't know of a more efficient method - with the possible exception of processing in several passes.

Comment: Sure. Will try that now. Thanks so much for your help.